# coordinate transformation and scaling

Tags: transformation, coordinate-systems, rotations

I have a global coordinate system that I need to transform to a local coordinate system. The new and old coordinate systems are shown below.

[image]

Using transformation rules, I came with with the coordinates in the new system. To get the coordinate system in the right position, it has to translated in the x and y directions, rotated about the x and z axis, and scaled. These formulas are shown below.

[image]

These formulas are not working, and I'm not sure why? As test points I tried out these,

Old System (0,-1.11270165)

New System (5.88729835,-10)

If anyone can enlighten me it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are those test points what it should be, or what you actually got? Maybe apply scaling before you translate?

Comment: Unless I made a mistake those test points should be correct. I calculated those by observation without any transformation rules.

Comment: You may want to fix your picture to make the question more clear. I'm not sure exactly what the new coordinate system should be.

Comment: The old coordinate system has been translated, rotated, and scaled to be in the position shown in the second picture(New System). Also  after looking at the points, in the old system 1.11270165 should be negative. I will update the problem.

Comment: Thanks, for me the new coordinate system is showing up way off to the side, making it difficult to tell where it should be.